# Picking complementary base pairs with python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I'm trying to develop a program where the users inputs a string of nucleotides and is given the complementary string (CAGT become GTCA, for example).

I've set up a dictionary:

```
dicto = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}
```

And I'm inputting user input in the form of a string to cross-reference with dictionary keys:

```
user = raw_input(prompt)
```

But, despite searching, I can't figure out how to how to use the multiple characters input by the user against the dictionary. I imagine it will be something like the below:

```
print dicto[x for x in user]
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: The dictionary expects a single letter, so it should be `dicto[x] for x in user`. Now that defines a generator and you still need to join the transformed letters: `''.join(dicto[x] for x in user)`. Note that you can also use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Comment: `dicto[x for x in user]` tries to pass a generator to `dicto`, which will not work. Maybe you want `[dicto[x] for x in user]` if you want a list. Of course, this simply could be something like: `for x in user: print(dicto[x])`. As an aside, you *really should be using Python 3*

Comment: @a_guest `str.translate` would definitely be the preferred way of doing this

Answer (score 3):

For this, using `str.translate` would be appropriate. Like so:

```py
#!python2
import string
trans = string.maketrans("ACTG", "TGAC")
user = raw_input()
print user.translate(trans)
```

```
#!python3
trans = str.maketrans('ACTG', 'TGAC')
user = input()
print(user.translate(trans))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
>>> dicto = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}
>>> user = 'ACTG'
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(*user)(dicto)
('T', 'G', 'A', 'C')
>>> ''.join(_)
'TGAC'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
print("".join([dicto[x] for x in user]))
```

What this does:
Create a list with the right base pairs, looked up in dicto:

```
[dicto[x] for x in user]
```

And feed this list to `"".join()` which creates a single string, by inserting the string it is called on between all List elements (empty string here, space is a common option)